# Deleting Member of an array of classes C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I know there are questions similar to this question but I've tried all the answers given and it still will not work in my program.

I have created an Array of Classes to be accessible across different classes, it is as follows,

```
static public Book[] Books = new Book[5];
```

I have implemented methods to add members to the array and change members in the array but i can not delete members in the array. The code is as follow,

```
if (BookEntries >= 1 && DeleteItem == 1)
{ 
    ChangeSelected = true;
    Books[0].Remove() //Remove array member at position 0
    //Or also tried
    Books = Books.Where(val => val != 0).ToArray();
    //Or also tried
    Books.RemoveAt(0)
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("----- Book {0} Has Been Deleted -----", DeleteItem);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated, If you need any additional information please ask. Cheers

Comment: Arrays are immutable(ish). You cannot alter their size once allocated. All you can do is reallocate a new array. If you need dynamic size, then use a `List`.

Comment: Is it possible to convert and array to a list, alter, then return to an array??

Comment: why are you using array at the first place if you need a dynamic collection?

Comment: Using `List<Book>` is the right way to handle things. You may, if you insist, create a list from a list by passing it to the constructor, or convert the list to an array by calling `ToArray`. I suspect the insistence of using array comes from a teacher that told you so... if so, that teacher probably wants you to either: A) allocate a new array, copy the contents to the new array or B) use a variable for the number of items in the array and iterate over the array using a `for` loop and move keep them compact at the start of the array.

Comment: @Theraot is correct, my assessment specifies use of arrays, but i agree completely a list would've been much more practical.

Comment: Thankyou all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

### Removing an item from an array

**Option one: Don't use an array.**

What you need is a dynamic structure, this is a solved problem, please let yourself step on the shoulders of giants and use `List<T>`:

```
static public List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();
```

You may add items like this:

```
Books.Add(item);
```

Or insert them:

```
Books.Insert(index, item);
```

Then you can remove items like this:

```
var indexToRemove = 0;
Books.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
```

Done.

*A list uses an array internally, like, this is literally the same thing you are trying to, except you don't have to do it because it is already done. I wish for your teacher to teach you to reuse code.*

**Option two: Use a List as proxy.**

By the powers tha be, you are stuck declaring your structure like this:

```
static public Book[] Books = new Book[5];
```

You may use a `List<Book>` as a middle step:

```
var indexToRemove = 0;
var list = new List<Book>(Books);
list.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
Books = list.ToArray();
```

Done.

*You used arrays, so this is technically correct. And remember, [technically correct is the best kind of correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo).*

**Option three: Linq.**

A bit more convoluted, you may use Linq to filter items by their index...

```
var indexToRemove = 0;
Books = Books.Where((item, index) => index != indexToRemove).ToArray();
```

*This is rarely what you want to do, although there are a few situations where it might suffice, you probably want lists anyway.*

**Option four: for loop.**

Here the idea is that the size of your array is not the number of items, but the maximun capacity you may have. Instead, you store a separate field for the number of items:

```
static public Book[] Books = new Book[5];
static public int BooksCount = 0;
```

To add items you do the following:

```
var index = BooksCount;
BooksCount++;
Books[index] = item;
```

To remove them... you need a for loop:

```
var indexToRemove = 0;
for (int index = indexToRemove + 1; index < BooksCount; index++)
{
    Books[index - 1] = Books[index];
}
BooksCount--;
Books[BooksCount] = default(Book); // null?
```

Ok, what's going on here?

Let's say you have a capacity of five elements, and you currently have four elements stored:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And you want to remove the second element. You start by copying each element after the second one place to the left, until you reach the last element:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

=>
the second element is index 1 (remember we start at 0)    
=> indexToRemove = 1
=> index = indexToRemove + 1
=> index = 2

=>
index = 2, index is less than 4 (there are four elements)
copy element at index 2 to index 1
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | C | C | D |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

=>
index = 3, index is less than 4 (there are four elements)
copy element at index 3 to index 2
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | C | D | D |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

=>
index = 4, index is NOT less than 4 (there are four elements)
```

Then decrement the number of elements, and erase the last one:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | C | D | D |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+

=>

+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | C | D |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
There are three elements
```

Done.

*This is probably what your teacher wants you to do. There is value in figuring this out by yourself... sorry.*

Note that it would be a good idea to encapsulate `BooksCount`, you don't want to accidentally change it to a wrong value... in fact, why don't you make a class that encapsulate the array and the count? Well, that's how `List<T>` works (well, I didn't tell you how to insert, or what to do when you run out of space on the array, yet what you need is all in this post, and `if`, you need `if`s).

*Ah, by the way, there is an structure called "linked list", that's another thing.*

**Option five: allocate and copy**

You may treat your array as actually immutable. In this scenario each operation results in creating a copy. This may be good for parallelism...

Using this definition:

```
static public Book[] Books = new Book[5];
```

You can add like this:

```
var replacement = new Book[Books.Length + 1];
Array.Copy(Books, 0, replacement, 0, Books.Length);
replacement[Books.Length] = item;
Books = replacement;
```

You can insert like this:

```
var replacement = new Book[Books.Length + 1];
Array.Copy(Books, 0, replacement, 0, index);
replacement[index] = item;
Array.Copy(Books, index, replacement, index + 1, Books.Length - index);
Books = replacement;
```

*Tested.*

And you can remove like this:

```
var indexToRemove = 0;
var replacement = new Book[Books.Length - 1];
Array.Copy(Books, 0, replacement, 0, indexToRemove);
Array.Copy(Books, indexToRemove + 1, replacement, indexToRemove, Books.Length - indexToRemove - 1);
Books = replacement;
```

*Tested.*

Done.

**Option seven: Did I say you need a for loop?**

No, you don't. You can use `Array.Copy` to remove even if are changing the array. We are back on this definition:

```
static public Book[] Books = new Book[5];
static public int BooksCount = 0;
```

You can remove items like this:

```
Array.Copy(Books, indexToRemove + 1, Books, indexToRemove, BooksCount - indexToRemove - 1);
BooksCount--;
Books[BooksCount] = default(Book); // null?
```

It is the same thing. You don't have to write a for loop.

Comment: Very detailed answer and the first method i tried has worked. Cheers